Creating new SR via postman
I'm creating a new SR via postman.
{
"description": "New test",
"reportedpriority": 2,
"location": "NL638206",
"classstructureid":68850,
"siteid":"ABC",
"failurecode":"LFMNLCOA"
}
I'm seeing this error.
"message": "BMXAA4521E - The internal representation of the failure report is not valid. The set members do not make up a valid report. You might need to delete the report and reenter it.",
"statusCode": "400"
New SR with failurecode works fine in Maximo.
I have also checked MAximo integration logs but there's nothing useful related to this error.
Any hints/advice is highly appreciated.
Thanks!
New SR with failurecode works fine in Maximo.
I have also checked MAximo integration logs but there's nothing useful related to this error.

I am assuming that you are using Maximo OLSC rest api instead of old mxrest api.
Try creating a record in Maximo and get the record from postman to see what data is loaded in record and compare with your payload. Hope this helps.
